# Explicitly Start Kafka Consumer In Main After method runs

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot service that consumes from a kafka topic. When i consume i perform certain tasks on the kafka message. Before i can perform these operations i need to wait for the service to load some data into caches that i have set up. My issue is if i set kafka consumer to autostart it starts consuming before the cache loads and it errors out.

I am trying to explicitly start the consumer after i load the cache however i get null pointer exceptions.

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.server}")
    String server;

    @Value("${kafka.port}")
    String port;

    @Value("${kafka.group.id}")
    String groupid;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server+":"+port);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupid);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        // config.put("security.protocol","SASL_PLAINTEXT");
        // config.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka");

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setAutoStartup(false);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

KafkaListener

```java
    @Service
    public class KafkaConsumer {

    @Autowired
    AggregationService aggregationService;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    private final CounterService counterService;

    public KafkaConsumer(CounterService counterService) {
        this.counterService = counterService;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "gliTransactionTopic", group = "gliDecoupling", id = "gliKafkaListener")
    public boolean consume(String message,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partition,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("Inside kafka listener :" + message+" partition :"+partition.toString()+" offset :"+offset.toString());
    aggregationService.run();
            return true;
        }



}
```

service To start stop

```java
    @Service
    public class DecouplingController {

        @Autowired
        private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;



        public void stop() {
            MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
                    .getListenerContainer("gliKafkaListener");
            listenerContainer.stop();
        }

        public void start() {
            MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
                    .getListenerContainer("gliKafkaListener");
            listenerContainer.start();
        }


    }
```

main method

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DecouplingApplication {

        Ignite ignite;


        static IgniteCache<Long, MappingsEntity> mappingsCache;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DecouplingApplication.class, args);

            Ignition.setClientMode(true);
            Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite("ignite");
            loadCaches(ignite);




        }

        public static boolean loadCaches(Ignite ignite) {

            mappingsCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("MappingsCache");


            mappingsCache.loadCache(null);

            System.out.println("Data Loaded");

            DecouplingController dc=new DecouplingController();
            dc.start();

            return true;
        }

    }
```

Below is the exception

```
    Data Loaded
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ignite.spring.decoupling.controller.DecouplingController.start(DecouplingController.java:126)
        at com.ignite.spring.decoupling.DecouplingApplication.loadCaches(DecouplingApplication.java:64)
        at com.ignite.spring.decoupling.DecouplingApplication.main(DecouplingApplication.java:37)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually creating an object of `DecouplingController` , autowire the dependency in DecouplingApplication.

```
@Autowired

DecouplingController deDecouplingController;
```

The `ApplicationContext` which deals with autowired dependencies is not aware about the object you manually created using "new". The autowired `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` is unknown to the  new `DecouplingController` object you created.

Comment: I did the following
@Autowired
 static
 DecouplingController decouplingController;

decouplingController.start();

Still get the below
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ignite.spring.decoupling.DecouplingApplication.loadCaches(DecouplingApplication.java:66)
 at com.ignite.spring.decoupling.DecouplingApplication.main(DecouplingApplication.java:41)

Comment: Dont make the autowired variable static

Comment: It says i have to make it static as i am calling it in the main springapplication class.

    @Autowired
    DecouplingController decouplingController;
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(DecouplingApplication.class, args);
  cache.load();
  decouplingController.start();  
 }

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `gliKafkaListener1` was not registred an some part of `ConsumerConfig/ListenerConfig`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please add some details to explain why you think this is the solution. In its current form, it reads like a guess, even if that is not your intention.